# javascript - call to function not passing parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

Tearing my hair out!!

I have the following code snippet similar to this:

```
function checkCountry(countrycode)
{
    //var countrycode="GB";
    var country = getCountry(countrycode);
    alert("checkCountry: country = "+country);


}

function getCountry(countrycode)
{
    var len = arguments.length;
    alert("getCountry: len = "+len);
    alert("getCountry: countrycode = "+countrycode);
    return countrycode;
}
```

checkCountry() is called from another js function.

The problem is that whatever I pass to getCountry() from checkCountry(), the countrycode in getCountry() is always an empty string.

I have tried passing string literals, ie "GB"; I have tried changing the getCountry() function name;  I have moved getCountry() to the same js file as checkCountry().

The arguments.length in getCountry() appears to be an empty string from the alert which shows 'getCountry: len = '; I thought it would be 0 or 'undefined'.

When I move the getCountry() code into checkCountry(), it works!  But I need/want getCountry() to be reuseable.

Couldn't find the answer from previous questions but I apologise if it is out there somewhere.

Comment: Please add a **[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)** which shows the actual problem.

Comment: That is the crux of the problem.  I'll edit it to take out the blah! and just leave the alerts.

Comment: Your example lacks the "verifiable" part. What you've posted works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/wyhe8qa9/

Comment: In which case it must be my ide!  Running NuSphere PHPeditor on Windows 10 with IE11.

Comment: Andreas - Never used jsfiddle before.  Following your link just gives me a bouncing cloud with the infinity symbol inside!

Comment: Enable JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two function but not calling any one of them. For example if you make checkCountry() self-executing or call it you get what you desire.

```
checkCountry();
```

OR

```
(function checkCountry()
{
    var countrycode="GB";
    var country = getCountry(countrycode);
})();
```

You can achieve what you want like this :

```
var x = {};
x.checkCountry = function(){
    var countrycode="GB";
    var country = getCountry(countrycode);
}

x.getCountry = function(countrycode){
    var len = arguments.length;
    alert("getCountry: len = "+len);
    alert("getCountry: countrycode = "+countrycode);

};
x.checkCountry();
```

Comment: Thanks for that but checkCountry() is being called from another function with a parameter.  Another edit!

Comment: There are no errors in the code.It should work if the functions are visible to calling function.

Comment: Just as  Andreas suggested.  Must be my ide.

Comment: Thanks both of you for v quick response.

Comment: Just as  Andreas said.  Thanks both for the fast replies.  Back to the drawing board!!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the codes:

```
function checkCountry()
{
    var countrycode="GB";
    var country = getCountry(countrycode);
    alert("checkCountry: country = "+country);
}

function getCountry(countrycode)
{
    var len = arguments.length;
    alert("getCountry: len = "+len);
    alert("getCountry: countrycode = "+countrycode);
    return countrycode;
}
```

Can you check if there's anything else wrong in the project/environment.
Is there any way the function name is duplicated/replaced elsewhere in your project.
You can set alert in each step of the functions, and then call checkCountry() and see from where it is going wrong/missing.

Ps- in my environment I copied the 2 functions, and called
checkCountry() function (on a button click for example).
Each time I got 3 alerts showing the follwing values:

```
getCountry: len = 1
getCountry: countrycode = GB
checkCountry: country = GB
```

So the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: _"There is nothing wrong in the codes"_ - Then why an answer? That's a comment and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Tanvir. I have checked all project files with a search; there are no other same named js functions. The codebase is fairly mature and calls between functions in different js files are working fine.  The call from checkCountry() to getCountry() is the only one (at present);  I aim to make getCountry() reuseable (if I ever get it to workon my machine!!).

Comment: Andreas - Tanvir gave me some ideas on how to track my problem which I think was good of him and certainly within the spirit of what I thought SO was all about.